# Security Alert from Google Play Console?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-signin

I've implemented google login and published App on Play Store. But after app published on play store Google Login doesn't work and I found solution for this problem i.e. copy SHA-1 key from Play Console and replace Google Api SHA-1 key with it.
And after that app working fine but above mentioned Security Alert message is appears.

Complete Alert message :

```
Security alert

Your app contains exposed Google Cloud Platform (GCP) API keys. Please see this Google Help Center 
article for details.

Vulnerable locations:

com.asdf.zxcv.AbcActivity-><init>
```

I am trying to resolve this warning since last 2 days but I can't. 
Can anyone please help me to resolve this problem.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You cannot hard code the key string inside your activity's code. You must put it into strings.xml file and reference it in code using get getResources().getString(R.string.key_string_name)

Comment: ok sir. I am trying to do this.

Comment: Thank you very mush @fillobotto . It works fine now.

Comment: I put it as answer so you can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you declare and you the API key inside your code.
It's not advisable to use it as plain text hard-coded in Java code, however you could store it in `strings.xml` resources.

Assuming that you store in it that way:

```
<string name="api_key">Your key</string>
```

Then in Java code get it like:

```
context.getResources().getString(R.string.api_key)
```

Comment: I don't understand how is it more secure than using string directly in java/kotlin code.